# I have problem to connect me glassfish server from compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-18.04, glassfish-4

i´m using ubuntu 18.04 lts in google compute engine and glassfish server running perfectly as seen in the following image:

[image]

already configure a static ip to the gcp vm:

[image]

and i remove the S so I can access my server
[image]

and i also add port 8080 to be able to connect and nothing keeps throwing me error
already try like this :http://34.94.96.242:8080
and this: http://34.94.96.242:4848 
And i still don't have access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try reaching your glassfish server inside the Compute Engine?, I mean using for example:

*curl localhost:[PORT]*

in the terminal and see the output, if OK, your installation is OK and probably there is a firewall rule missing, so you have to create it with the specific port.

For example for enabling traffic in port 22 for using SSH, you need to execute the following command in cloud shell:

*gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22*

or for opening port 8080

*gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-glassfish --allow tcp:808*

Take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) about how to set up firewall rules in GCP step-by-step.

Comment: Thank you very much with your help I was able to solve the problem and with the steps of this page:https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/administration/use-firewall/